# How to add new Dimension Attributes to the existing dimension through BIDS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008

I have a customer dimension. While creating cube and defining dimensions the default attributes will come along with the cube creation. I want to add some more attributes after creating the dimensions. How to do this. I tried with "Add Business Intelligence" option, but I failed. Is there any way to do like that. If we remove the dimension and add the dimension again, we can have a interface as "Select dimension attributes". But with out deleting the existing dimension, how to add the attributes to that dimension. Following screen illustrates adding dimension attributes. How to see this interface for existing dimension.
[image]

After clicking the dimension attribute tab and clicking on the "Edit datasource" option.. following screen is showing. Here where we can add the attributes?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your DSV includes the columns that you want to add as attributes, and assuming that you have an existing dimension, you cannot open the Dimension Wizard again to add more attributes to your dimension. Instead, on the Dimension Structure page (as shown in Diego's screen shot), you have the Attributes pane on the far left where each attribute is listed and you have the Data Source View showing the diagram of your table. You drag a column from the diagram on the right to the Attributes pane on the left. That creates a new attribute.

[image]

The image above shows the cursor appearance as you drag the column into the Attributes pane. The image below shows the Attribute pane after you release the mouse button - the new attribute appears as shown.

[image]

Comment: @Stacia.. thanks for your solution. But this is confusing me. Can you add the screen shots if possible please.

Comment: Screen shots added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit the DSV.

On the "Dimension Structure", "Data Source View" tab, right click any blank space and select "Edit Data Source View". It will bring you to the DSV. Do the changes you want on the DSV and they should be available to be picked as attributes once you get back to the "Dimension Structure"

[image]

Comment: @Diego.. thanks for your answer. But I am unable to find the locations what you are saying. Can you please post me the screen shots!

Comment: which version are you using? 2005 or 2008?

Comment: I think that is for calculation. For eg.. first name + last name like that. But we cannot add new attributes there. right!!

Comment: but where is this new attribute coming from? The DSV should show all available columns to be picked

Comment: Yeah... but how to add those new columns.. thats the question. :) Did you tried this?

Comment: is the column you want appearing on  the DSV?

Comment: No.. I will explain once again. In the image what you posted, in the left side pane there is one dimension and it has 3 dimension attributes right! Now i want to add the fourth one to it. How to do? Is it clear now?

Comment: I don't understand where is this new attribute coming from? did you add a new column on the table, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Stacia will work if the Dimension is based of a Named query.

If the dimension is based of the table then the "Data Source View" window is empty you cannot drag attributes.

The solution is to  add the attributes manually. Click "View Attributes as List" and add the attributes manually. Please see the link below. This helped me.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174567.aspx